# Linux history command

Tags: ubuntu-9.10, history

I am working on Ubuntu 9.10. I would like to ask if is there a way to print all the commands typed in Linux? I took a break of a few months on Linux and now I would like to have a list with everything I've tested ,tried starting with the period I've installed Linux (Ubuntu).

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `history` command. By default, bash only stores the last 500 commands I think.

Comment: +1 *only* the last 500? :P

Answer (score 2):

If you want the full history in a file, it is in `~/.bash_history` which has last 500 commands you typed in.

Comment: can you give me the command?

Comment: @linuxx: It is a **file**. You can open it with any application you like. Better copy it before you use new commands.

Comment: vi ~/.bash_history or cat ~/.bash_history | more